Two Flask application deploy in same server
I have a flask application deployed on the server, and I made a copy of the application with some modifications and also deployed it on the server. They all use Nginx as a proxy. I used flask-login for user login, and I ran into a problem. When I logged in with the first application, the Cookies stored a session value. When I logged in with the second application, there is still only one session value in the Cookies, and the second application can not log out (it did not actually log in) . When I logged out of the first application, the session value was deleted from the Cookies. How Do I get the login and logout functions of these two applications to work properly?
I tried configuring a different SECRET_KEY, but it didn't work out.

Have you tried changing the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME for two apps?

@BcK, Thank you very much, I tried to config SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, and my problem solved!
